# how to create valid XMLs

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am sending an XML input to one of the external system and that doesnt have an XSD.Now to make this valid, does the external system (team) needs to define the XSD or do I need to come up with one?

Assuming I need to create one, what is the right approach to do this in Java

Can someone clarify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it depends on you; usually XSD defines a contract; it tells other people how the XML will be done (not all the logical controls, but it can make understand how the XML will be); so basically if I was you I would first creat the XSD for my own XML file; I'll give this XSD to the external system's developers so they can understand that all the XMLs you'll provide will follow the created XSD
Then you can create you XML by using the created XSD (e.g. by using some XML Binding like JAXb o Jibx etc...)

Angelo